# First click on Nav Menu Button Giving Error and working fine after that ReactJs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, function, navigation

I am trying to make a hide/show navbar in ReactJS.
But on the first click I am getting this error and its working fine after the first click.

- Note: Its twice and i have no idea why

[image]

Here is my code and its only working (after first error) when

> setMenu(!menu);

is before

> nav.classList.toggle("nav-open");

otherwise the error just keeps coming.

```
export default function Navbar() {
  const [menu, setMenu] = useState(true);
  const nav = document.querySelector("nav");

  const openNav = () => {
    setMenu(!menu);
    nav.classList.toggle("nav-open");
  };

  return (
    <nav id="nav-wrapper">
      <header className="nav-header">
        <div
          className="arrow-btn"
          onClick={() => {
            openNav();
          }}
        >
          {menu ? (
            <Icon.HiChevronDoubleLeft size={20} className="arrows" />
          ) : (
            <Icon.HiChevronDoubleRight size={20} className="arrows" />
          )}
        </div>
        <img src={Profiledp} alt="." />
        <p className="name">Naman Pokhriyal</p>
      </header>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Just use `refs` instead of `document.querySelector`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the right way of doing this in React in the first place.  You're already using the `menu` state value to determine if the menu is open is not, so why not continue to use the `menu` state value to determine if the menu is open or not?  Something like this:

```
const openNav = () => {
    setMenu(!menu);
};

return (
  <nav id="nav-wrapper" className={menu ? "nav-open" : ""}>
  // etc.
);
```

Basically any time you're trying to directly manipulate the DOM in React, take a step back and try to find a way to manage that via state instead.  Direct DOM manipulation in React almost always leads to bugs unless you really know what you're doing under the hood in the framework.